# Critical damping oscilations - Equation in Fowles book

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I'm not understanding a passage in the Fowles's book, seventh edition, equation 3.4.9.

I understood that, considering:

- $x$ = position
- $\gamma$ = damping factor
- ${w_0}^2$ = k/m, where k is the stiffness of a spring
- $D = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}$

We can do:

$(D^2 + 2\gamma D + {w_0}^2)x = 0$

Using binomial theorem, we can do:

$(D + \gamma - \sqrt{{\gamma}^2 -{w_0}^2 })(D + \gamma + \sqrt{{\gamma}^2 -{w_0}^2 })x = 0$

Considering $q =\sqrt{{\gamma}^2 -{w_0}^2 }$, we have, for damping oscilations, $q = 0$.

So:

$(D + \gamma)(D + \gamma)x = 0$

In this way, we still have the factor $2{\gamma}Dx$, so the changing in order do not works. As an other artifice, we can do the following substitution:

$u = (D + \gamma)x$

In this way:

$u = Ae^{-{\gamma}t} \Rightarrow Ae^{-{\gamma}t} = (D + \gamma)x$

Now comes the passage that I did not understand:

(1) $ A = e^{{\gamma}t} (D + \gamma)x = D(xe^{{\gamma}t} )$

Where did go the term $\gamma(xe^{{\gamma}t} )$ ?

Comment: It was "Fowles Analytical Mechanics" the s's part was too much me...

Comment: @Kuhlambo you are right, it is not d/dx it is d/dt. I typed wrong,  I will correct it

Comment: @Kuhlambo Yes, I typed wrong in this point too. I already corrected it. Thank you

Comment: @Kuhlambo I guess I corrected the mistakes, Did I?

Comment: It's a crazy technique to use on this problem, i would love to see the rest of this derivation.^^

Comment: @Kuhlambo you can see it in the book, if you want, I can put the rest here later

Comment: No don't worry about that. I'll see if I come across the book at some point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step:
$A = e^{{\gamma}t} (D + \gamma)x = D(xe^{\gamma t})$

Is just the product rule backwards see: \begin{align}D(xe^{\gamma t}) 
& = e^{\gamma t} \dot x +\gamma e^{\gamma t} x \\
 & =e^{\gamma t} Dx+\gamma  e^{\gamma t}x \\ 
&= e^{{\gamma}t} (D + \gamma)x
\end{align}